# Identify Clash from Day and Time Array

Tags: php

I have checked other SO questions but can't seem to find anything related to this - point me in the right direction if I missed something.

I currently have the following array containing a day and time (requested meeting time):

```
Array (
    [0] =>
        day => 'Thursday',
        start_time => '14:00',
        end_time => '15:00'
    [1] =>
        day => 'Thursday',
        start_time => '16:30',
        end_time => '17:30'
)
```

The user is required to attend both of these times. What I am attempting to do is compare against another array containing a users current appointments and detect if there is a clash / time overlap issue

```
Array (
    [0] =>
        day => 'Monday',
        start_time => '09:00',
        end_time => '13:00'
    [1] =>
        day => 'Wednesday',
        start_time => '10:45',
        end_time => '11:15'
    [2] =>
        day => 'Thursday',
        start_time => '16:45',
        end_time => '17:45'
)
```

Using the above example I want to identify there is a clash with the second timeslot `[1] =>` of the first array (proposed meetings) which clashes with the third timeslot `[2] =>` of the second array (current meetings).

I have seen examples with timestamps and full dates, but not just days and start / end times.

Comment: Are these in a database? Because it would be really easy to query and get only the conflicting rows back as the result. Much more efficient as well.

Comment: They are indeed, all users current meetings are stored in one table with each day, start_time and end_time, then the new meeting is stored in another table again with the same data. How would you go about it using a MySQL query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they are all in a database, a query for conflicts could look like:

```
SELECT `plan`.*
FROM `plan`
    JOIN `current` ON `plan`.`day`=`current`.`day`
WHERE
    `plan`.`start_time` < `current`.`end_time`
    AND `plan`.`end_time` > `current`.`start_time`
```

where `current` is the table with the current schedule and `plan` is the table with the user's schedule. I haven't tested this just because I don't have an example, but this should return rows where the day is the same and `plan` times overlap `current` times.

edit: You might also want to do stuff like mark `current` as tentative if they are not required. you can put that into the query where clause.

Also the `>` and `<` mean that the start and end minute are not inclusive. so if one ends at the same time as another begins, this will not flag them as a conflict. If you want the start/end minute to be inclusive, change them to `>=` and `<=`.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, that makes sense now. The end result is to have a list of all 20 staff and then a mark next to any members of staff who clash with the planned times. Would the only way to achieve that be to run the query 20 times?

Comment: @lethalMango In order to run the query for individual staff, you would have to add to the where clause something like `AND plan.staff_id=12345`. You can do that, or you can just leave out that part in the where clause and select for all staff then you can just loop through the result, make an array of scheduled events and conflicts. Then when looping through the staff look to see if the staff exists in the conflicts for that event. If I had a table structure and what output you want I could make something that might help more.

Comment: I managed to get everything I wanted from your answer and comment, thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it this way

```
$slot1 = Array (
        0 => array (
                'day' => 'Thursday',
                'start_time' => '14:00',
                'end_time' => '15:00' 
        ),
        1 => array (
                'day' => 'Thursday',
                'start_time' => '16:30',
                'end_time' => '17:30' 
        ) 
);

$slot2 = Array (
        0 => array (
                'day' => 'Monday',
                'start_time' => '09:00',
                'end_time' => '13:00' 
        ),
        1 => array (
                'day' => 'Wednesday',
                'start_time' => '10:45',
                'end_time' => '11:15' 
        ),
        2 => array (
                'day' => 'Thursday',
                'start_time' => '16:45',
                'end_time' => '17:45' 
        ) 
);

echo "<pre>";
$format = "l H:s";
foreach($slot1 as $value)
{
    $slot1Start = DateTime::createFromFormat ($format , $value ['day'] . " " . $value['start_time'] );
    $slot1End = DateTime::createFromFormat ( $format , $value ['day'] . " " . $value['end_time'] );

    foreach($slot2 as $value2)
    {
        $slot2Start = DateTime::createFromFormat ( $format , $value2 ['day'] . " " .$value2['start_time'] );
        $slot2End = DateTime::createFromFormat ( $format , $value2 ['day'] . " " .$value2 ['end_time'] );


        if ($slot1Start <= $slot2End && $slot1End >= $slot2Start) {
            echo sprintf ( "Even Overlap on %s %s-%s AND %s %s-%s", $value ['day'], $value ['start_time'], $value ['end_time'],
                    $value2 ['day'], $value2 ['start_time'], $value2 ['end_time'] ), PHP_EOL;
        }

    }
}
```

Output

```
Even Overlap on Thursday 16:30-17:30 AND Thursday 16:45-17:45
```

Answer (score 0):

There are your a bit modified arrays code

```
   $current_sheduler = Array (
        [0] =>
            day => 'Thursday',
            start_time => '14:00',
            end_time => '15:00'
        [1] =>
            day => 'Thursday',
            start_time => '16:30',
            end_time => '17:30'
    )

    $user_plans = Array (
        [0] =>
            plan_name => 'event1',
            day => 'Monday',
            start_time => '09:00',
            end_time => '13:00'
        [1] =>
            plan_name => 'event2',
            day => 'Wednesday',
            start_time => '10:45',
            end_time => '11:15'
        [2] =>
            plan_name => 'event3',
            day => 'Thursday',
            start_time => '16:45',
            end_time => '17:45'
    )
```

Here is way to process your arrays and catches if event planned by user matches time from your first array

```
foreach($user_plans as $plan){
  foreach($current_sheduler as current){
     if($plan['day']==$current['day']){
       if(
         ($plan['start_time']>=$current['start_time']) &&
         ($plan['end_time']<=$current['end_time'])
       ){
          echo "Event {$plan['plan_name']} is working now!";
       }
     }
  }
}
```

This is general logic, for situation, when match means full period match only.

Another notice: befor compare times, you need to recount them into counted minutes format.

Comment: you would need to loop over `$current_sheduler` as well because it is a multi dimensional array. This also means you will end up with `count($current_sheduler) * count($user_plans)` number of iterations which is far from ideal.

Comment: Yah, I agree, there two loop nessesary, fixed my code. And yah, this isn't most effective solution, will need many itterations.

Comment: Also, this doesn't cover all combinations of time overlap. e.g. plan=10-12 and current=9-11 or plan=9-12 and current=10-11.

Comment: Hmm... Depends from task... If plan and current must match in time for full period, then my code is correct, if ever partily match is accepted, then you are right

Comment: $user_plans[2] and $current_sheduler[1] overlap partly. Your code correctly identifies it, but would fail the other way around. For all possible combinations, change your if statement to say `if(($plan['start_time'] < $current['end_time']) && ($plan['end_time'] > $current['start_time']))`.